# Paid membership pro plugin issue with payment process in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I have installed the paid memberships pro plugin in my word press site and integrated with  my stripe account. but at the time of membership level checkout (payment time) after filling up card no. and all the required filled its showing error like "Please complete all required fields". my stripe account account is on test mode only and i have set up all test API also.

Currently i have issue with stripe account card number. Its not accept any card number.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Stripe test credit card numbers. Check out https://stripe.com/docs/testing

Once you have a valid credit card number, pmPro validation should work and you should be good to go.

Edit:

Looking at your post again, I see you say "my stripe account is on test mode". You can't set your stripe account to be on either mode. It always has both working. In WordPress you need to set your environment to Sandbox/Testing. You can do this by going to Memberships -> Payment Settings -> Gateway Environment. Lastly, make sure all Page Settings are set (you have pages for each of the dropdowns).

Comment: I tried all test card number but none of them working. Its always shows error please fill all required fields on card number.

Comment: Same issue.Got any solutions.if so, please post it.